# htmlspecialchars wrong use?

Tags: php, mysql, row

Hey guys,
looked at the php docs and googled around, but no joy. This is my code snippet, the htmlspecialchars doesn't seem to work, wrong use of it?

```
$query="SELECT * FROM likes";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$liked=htmlspecialchars($liked, ENT_QUOTES);
$liked=$_POST['liked'];

$query = "INSERT INTO likes VALUES ('','$name','$liked')";
```

thanks guys,
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting it with `$_POST['liked']` in the immediately-following line. Switch the two lines. Or, just pass the POST var into the function directly:

```
$liked=htmlspecialchars($_POST['liked'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Anyway you should be using `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape your SQL query params. Save HTML escapes only for when you're about to display the data.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock, that worked perfectly! :) If you don't mind, what should I add to escape the mysql injections? (Really new at PHP and MySQL)! Thanks again

Comment: Or use parametrized queries, which will protect you from SQL injection attacks.  (`mysql_real_escape_string()` is vulnerable when using some character sets for the connection, since it will not consider locale-specific quotation marks.)

Comment: @James Whelton: Escape each of your values by passing them through the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function. Do this before constructing your SQL query.

Comment: So:    mysql_real_escape_string($liked, $name);

Comment: @James: Call it once per variable, e.g. `$liked = mysql_real_escape_string($liked); $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);`